# How to undo a Bevel modification?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, edges

Bevel in Blender is "simulated" by splitting edges into multiple faces. This results in a lot of crap which makes it harder to modify an edge afterwards. What is the best way to deal with it? I would like to be able to easily undo a bevel modification and reapply it after a line or vertex modification. I mean in a long term method, of course I can use the undo history for short but this is not usable after save and other modifications took place in between.
Please keep in mind that Bevel of different edges might have different parameters or diameters and so on.
I know you can store a Bevel modification per mesh but can this be done for parts of a mesh also?
If there is no easy way to manage a Bevel what might be the best procedure to disbevel an edge?

Comment: Modifications which were made by editing actual geometry (e.g. beveling in Edit mode) can't be "undone" as usual (unless `Ctrl`+`Z`). If it's important to undo some complex changes you can try to create simpler version of your mesh and add **Shrinkwrap** modifier on it, in order to wrap new mesh atop of beveled one. One of advantages of using modifiers is that they allow you to edit geometry without touching mesh itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the bevel modifier, and not apply it, that way it remains editable, and suppressible.

Also You can Limit by Vertex Groups.

Everything you want all in one Modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Also here's a tip that make your life a 100x easier. Hit Cmd+z to undo something you didn't want to do, like a mistake or so.